# invalid hook call with SWR library

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, swr

I'm trying to do a delete request using the `SWR library` with react hook.
I know that hooks can't be called inside return(). but how do I delete request using useSWR in my react hook project. thank you

```
const page = () => {
    function onDelete(id) {
        const { data: deleted } = useSWR(`http://example.com/api/project/delete/${id}`, fetcher)
    }

    return (
        // some rendered component
        <Button 
            onClick={() => onDelete(project.id)}
            label="Delete"
        />
    )
}
```

error : [image: Unhandled Runtime Error]

Comment: You can't use hook inside function.

Comment: is there a solution for me to do a delete request to the server when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a hook inside the function, You can use conditional fetching. check here
https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching

```
const page = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(null);
  const { data: deleted } = useSWR(
    id ? `http://example.com/api/project/delete/${id}` : null,
    fetcher
  );

  return (
    // some rendered component
    <Button onClick={() => setId(project.id)} label="Delete" />
  );
};
```