# Uncaught Error in react component invalid hook, useSWR

Tags: javascript, reactjs

using a useSWR wrapper and I cannot find the issue that is causing the invalid hook error in the Player component.

I went through https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

I didnt have this problem before with react useContext. I refactored and switched to useSWR, router v6. The error is new

error details:

```
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in one of your React components:
...
line 115341
line 115342    e.default = function (n) {
line 115343        var e = n.title,
line 115344             t = void 0 !== e && e,
line 115345             a = n.subTitle,
    ...
    at e.default (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:115343:15)
    at div
    at Player (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8314:108)
    at div
    at div
    at Tab (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6132:104)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:122353:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:122286:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:121095:5)
    at SWRConfig$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:137530:21)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2528:86)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

react-dom.development.js:12056  Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:1)
    at useRef (react.development.js:1515:1)
    at e.default (ReactNetflixPlayer.js:1:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
```

here is the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
     "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-netflix-player": "^1.1.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "swr": "^1.3.0"
},
```

here is the code

```
// useSharedState.js
---

import useSWR from 'swr'

export const useSharedState = (key, initial) => {
  const { data: state, mutate: setState } = useSWR(key, {
    fallbackData: initial,
  })

  return [state, setState]
}


// Container.js
---

import { useSharedState } from "../../hooks/useSharedState"
import useSWR from 'swr'

function Container() {

const { data: item } = useSWR(`/endpoint`)

return (
        item && (
    <div><button
          onClick={() => {setPlayerItem(item)  }} ... >
    ...</div>

);
}

export default Container;


// Player.js
---


import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import ReactNetflixPlayer from "react-netflix-player";

const Player = () => {
const [playerItem, setPlayerItem] = useSharedState('playerContext')

 return (
      <React.Fragment>
      {playerItem && (
        <div id={"player"} >
          <ReactNetflixPlayer
          title={playerItem.title}
          backButton={() => { setPlayerItem(null) }}
          />
        </div>
        )}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
export default Player;


// Tab.js
---

import Player from "../Player"
...
function Tab() {

 return (
     <div>
        <Player />
    <React.Fragment>
       <Container />
       {columnData && <BodyColumn data={columnData}/>}
       ...
    </React.Fragment>
   </div>
);
}

export default Tab;
```

`<Tab>` is a component in `<App>`
The `Player` component is rendered after a button is clicked that sets data

there are other components with buttons that perform a click and set state by referencing `const [playerItem, setPlayerItem] = useSharedState('playerContext')`

thanks in advance

related [invalid hook call with SWR library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126375/invalid-hook-call-with-swr-library)

**edit:** https://codesandbox.io/s/invalid-hook-debugging-2v37wj

Comment: where are you using Container?

Comment: Seems the issue is in `ReactNetflixPlayer`. What is that?

Comment: @whygee sorry, I updated the code. `Container` is used in the return method of `Tab` component (`Player` is also used)

Comment: @DrewReese it is an external component from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-netflix-player. They also have [an example in their docs](https://github.com/Lucasmg37/react-netflix-player/blob/master/example/index.js). This component used to work in the past

Comment: If you comment it out does the error go away? Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: @DrewReese good idea here is the codesandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/invalid-hook-debugging-2v37wj. it shows the error on /tab page

Comment: The error comes from ReactNetflixPlayer package and has nothing to do with useSWR

Comment: sorry for not clarifying. click the play button

Comment: `react-netflix-player` has a peer dependency on React 16/17, see: https://github.com/Lucasmg37/react-netflix-player/blob/master/package.json#L51-L53. Seems it won't work with React 18.